# Where do I extend the AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a login system consisting of the following elements:

LoginActivity uses LoginController uses RestClient to call a web service with Execute(). I want the call to the web service to be performed asynchronously but I also need a dialog box to notify the user of relevant information while the call is being made. Execute does not return anything.

How will I go about doing this ? Where do I use AsyncTask ?

Comment: You can override onProgressUpdate method of AsyncTask to show dialog.publishProgress will call onProgressUdate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AsyncTask has a few methods that will help you with this.

Extend the AsyncTask:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void>

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
    // show progress dialog
  }

  @Overrride
  protected Void doInBackground(Object... params) {
    HttpUriRequest req = (HttpUriRequest) params[0];
    String myString = (String) params[1];

    // connect
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // hide dialog
  }
}
```

To execute this with parameters, try this:

```
myTask.execute(request, "aString");
```

Where request is an object of type HttpUriRequest. Remember the order of the parameters matter.

If you want to update the status while the service is connecting you can use this method as Rasel said:

```
onProgressUpdate() {
  // Update view in progress dialog
}
```

Comment: Alright. I'm probably asking like an idiot but it seems that doInBackground needs to return something. The method that I want executed by doInBackground saved all the data it needs internally and therefore does not return anything. Why can't I declare it void ?

Comment: Okay. One last thing. Where do you suggest I create my private CallServiceTask class? I will be needing it later in other parts of my app, so the obvious choice seems to be in RestClient. Is this correct? 
And what exactly am I declaring in "myTask extends AsyncTask<Var, Var, Var> ?

Comment: I would suggest having it as an own class which you can include where you want it. Just use new CallServiceTask().execute();
As for the Vars, the first is the input type to doInBackground (the ones you can put inside .execute() ), the second is the type you send to onProgressUpdate and the final is the result type from doInBackground which is sent to onPostExecute

Comment: I'm sorry to have yet another question, but what would the AsyncTask look like if I need execute() to have both HttpUriRequest and a String as parameters?

Specifically, what would private 
class CallServiceTask extends AsyncTask<Var, Var, Var>
look like?