# Android in Eclipse - Invoke File Writer class in Background

Tags: java, android, eclipse, text-files

When I click the button (btnPrintTardy) I need to generate a .txt file of whatever i have entered into a txtbox (editText1).

This is my File Writer java class.

```
import android.app.Activity;

import java.io.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class FileWriter extends Activity {
    EditText txtData;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    txtData = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    }


    public void onClick(View v) {
        // write in data folder
        try {
            File myFile = new File("/data/LatePass/StudentLatePass.txt");
            myFile.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
            OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = 
                                    new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            myOutWriter.append(txtData.getText());
            myOutWriter.close();
            fOut.close();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Finished writing StudentLatePass.txt'",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

                finish();
                };
}
```

I am calling this method from my "StudentActivity" however, this is where i am kind of stuck. I want to stay on my current screen activity, but run the filewriter in the background. So how would I call this?

I have tried

```
 public void UpdateStudenttxtfile(View View)
    {

    Intent intent = new Intent(View.getContext(), FileWriter.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    }
```

with no luck :(

Comment: Wot about writing the file using a thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using an AsyncTask for this background work instead of implementing as a separate activity:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Then, instead of sending an Intent, you just call:

```
EditText txtData = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
FileWriterTask task = new FileWriterTask();
task.execute(txtData.getText().toString());

public class FileWriterTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    // Do your filewriting here. The text should now be in params[0]
  }
}
```

Here's another answer about AsyncTask:
[Where do I extend the AsyncTask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224476/where-do-i-extend-the-asynctask/9224574#9224574)

Comment: See the link to my other answer.

Comment: How is this?

public class FileWriterTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
 public class FileWriter extends Activity {
  // GUI controls
  EditText txtData;

Comment: Yes, but I am a little confused on if this needs to be in its own async or inside the studentactivity.

Comment: Put it in a separate class. It's easier to understand that way. And remove the public void oncreate and public void onclick from inside your doInBackground method. You only need the code you had inside onClick. Replace myOutWriter.append(txtData.getText()); with myOutWriter.append(params[0]);

Comment: ... and here is where I am calling it. http://imgur.com/7LcBq 
The error is "Syntax error on token "execute", Identifier expected after this token"

Comment: Change the txtData.getText() inside execute to txtData.getText().toString(). Otherwise your code looks fine. Eclipse sometimes gives warnings that are not correct. Try removing the line and writing it once more.

Comment: I believe I had a bracket out of place which was causing the error. I have also moved the execute code to be called upon btnPrintTardy click.

http://i.imgur.com/AKqqw.jpg

However this seems to just crash the application. I figured the issue may be where it is trying to create the .txt

http://imgur.com/eFas9

I appreciate your help Eric soo much.

Comment: Are you getting an exception while writing the file? Anyway, I think you should try using this as a path to the file: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/StudentLatePass.txt".

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1, java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground(), at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200),