# Android in Eclipse - AsyncTask upon Button click initiates FileWriter

Tags: android, android-asynctask, background-process, filewriter

[Eric Nordvik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217283/eric-nordvik) has been helping me with this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529210/android-in-eclipse-invoke-file-writer-class-in-background) for some time now so big props to him.

This question has sort of evolved into an AsyncTask question so I figured I'd move it here. When my print button (btnPrintTardy) is click I was to start an AsyncTask to save whatever is in the edit text field (editText1) via FileWriter to the SD card as a .text .

So far here is my AsyncTask called "FileWriterTask"

```
package com.android.upgrayeddapps.latepass;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FileWriterTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
      @Override
      protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        // write in data folder
            try {
                File myFile = new File("/sdcard/StudentLatePass.txt");
                myFile.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
                OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = 
                                        new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                myOutWriter.append(params[0]);
                myOutWriter.close();
                fOut.close();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Finished writing StudentLatePass.txt'",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

                    finish();
                    return null;
                    }

    private Context getBaseContext() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }



    private void finish() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    };

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // clear text box
        finish();
    }
      }
```

Inside my Student Activity I am calling my FileWriterTask with this code.

```
public void UpdateStudenttxtfile(View View)
    {
        EditText txtData = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        FileWriterTask task = new FileWriterTask();
        task.execute(txtData.getText().toString());

    }
```

In my studentActivity layout I have the "printbutton's" on Click set to

```
android:onClick="UpdateStudenttxtfile"
```

Now at the moment when I run this I am getting a few exceptions and the program crashes.

```
I/dalvikvm(337): Jit: resizing JitTable from 512 to 1024

W/dalvikvm(337): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)

E/AndroidRuntime(337): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1

E/AndroidRuntime(337): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)

E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)

E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)

E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)

E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)

E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)

E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)

E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

E/AndroidRuntime(337): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)

E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:68)

E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:231)

E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at com.android.upgrayeddapps.latepass.FileWriterTask.doInBackground(FileWriterTask.java:29)

E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at com.android.upgrayeddapps.latepass.FileWriterTask.doInBackground(FileWriterTask.java:1)

E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)

E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)

E/AndroidRuntime(337):  ... 4 more

D/dalvikvm(337): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1381K, 60% free 2709K/6727K, external 2011K/2137K, paused 7ms+8ms

I/Process(337): Sending signal. PID: 337 SIG: 9
```

Comment: do you really need an AsyncTask to do that? I mean - how much stuff will someone write in that EditText?

Comment: Eventually we will feed in data from database. ie: Student Name, Time, period, tardy count, warnings, etc. Since I am new to android I am not positive on the best way to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android you can not update the UI from any thread other than the UI thread.
In your code you're showing a Toast in `doInBackground()` which is executing in a separate thread.